# Time sleep function not working with string

Tags: xbmc

Want to import a string from xbmc setting and put it in the time.sleep function.
Code:

```
debouncing_video  =  settings.getSetting( "Debounce_video")
debouncing_audio  =  settings.getSetting( "Debounce_audio")
time.sleep(denouncing_video)
```

If i replace the (debouncing_video) with a 3, it wait for tree second. If i print the string (denouncing_video) it say 3 but if i put time.sleep(debouncing_video) it is not working
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value returned is a string. Convert it to an int:

```
debouncing_video  =  int(settings.getSetting( "Debounce_video"))
```

See the [API](http://mirrors.xbmc.org/docs/python-docs/xbmcaddon.html#Addon-getSetting):

```
getSetting(id) -- Returns the value of a setting as a unicode string.
```

You would have seen an error in the `xbmc.log` that says `TypeError: a float is required`.